# Pointfree composed function with spreaded arguments

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, pointfree

I'm trying to figure out if there is a pattern for writing pointfree composed function when the arguments should be spreaded in curried composing functions
i.e (with Ramda):

```
add_1_and_multiply = (add, mul) => R.compose(R.multiply(mul), R.add(1))(add)
add_1_and_multiply(3, 5)  // 20
```

How to write `add_1_and_multiply` in pointfree style?

Comment: Try to use composition for `multiply(add(1, x), y)` instead of `multiply(y, add(1, x))`: `R.compose(R.multiply, R.add(1))`

Comment: @Bergi that is exactly what I concluded in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can easily combine pointfree style and non-unary arity.
Think first what should be the type of the resulting and composed functions:

```
// Compose:         (B  ->  C) -> (A  ->  B) ->  A  ->  C
const compose = f => g => x => f(g(x))
// Add:              A  ->  A  ->  A
const add = x => y => x + y
// Mul:              A  ->  A  ->  A
const mul = x => y => x * y

// Add1:             A  ->  A
const add1 = add(1)

// Add1AndMul:       A  ->         A  ->  A
//   because:
//     Add1:         A  ->  A
//     Mul:                 A  ->  A  ->  A
const add_1_and_mul = compose(mul)(add1)

// Mul4:             A  ->  A
const mul_4 = add_1_and_mul(3)
const result = mul_4(5) //> 20
```

---

Ramda has `uncurryN` so you can wrap it around the `compose` and get rid of the currying of the resulting function.

```
const add_1_and_multiply = R.uncurryN(2, R.compose(R.multiply, R.add(1)))
let result2 = add_1_and_multiply(3, 5) //> 20
```

---

To add another function to the "chain" you need to compose it with previous function.

```
// Add1AndMul:          A -> A -> A
const add1_mul = compose(mul)(add1)
```

This is our desired signature.

```
//                      1         2         3
// Add1AndMulAndAdd:    A ->      A ->      A -> A
//  which is:           |         |         |
//      Add1:           A -> A    |         |
//      Mul:                 A -> A -> A    |
//      Add:                           A -> A -> A
```

So somehow we have to pass those A<sub>2</sub> and A<sub>3</sub> without any "points".
Let's try just simple composition and analyze it:

```
let add1_mul_add = compose(add)(add1_mul)
```

Remeber signature of compose: `(E -> F) -> (D -> E) -> D -> F`!
Analyzing it in steps:

1. We supply our `add` function signature instead of `(E -> F)`

   ```
    (E -> F     )
    (A -> A -> A)
   ```

   We conclude that

   ```
    E = A
    F = A -> A
   ```
2. We do the same to `(D -> E)` and `add1_mul`

   ```
    (D -> E     )
    (A -> A -> A)
   ```

   We conclude that

   ```
    D = A
    E = A -> A
   ```

But we can already see a contradiction there!
Conclusion in step 2 contradicts conclusion in step 1:
`E` cannot be `A` and `A -> A` at the same time.

Therefore we cannot compose `add` and `add1_mul` and our `add1_mul_add` will throw an error.

Let's try to workaround the problem and fix it breaking our promise of pointfree style.

```
const add1_mul_add = x => compose(add)(add1_mul(x))
```

I'm going to break some rules and mix signatures with code to illustrate my point:

```
x -> (A -> A -> A) -> (x -> A -> A) -> A -> A -> A
                       ||
                       \/
x -> (A -> A -> A) -> (A -> A) -> A -> A -> A
     (E -> F     ) -> (D -> E) -> D -> F
```

So we got our correct compose signature! How to get rid of the `x` variable to go back to pointfree?
We can try to look for obvious patterns, like for example... our ye olde function composition!

```
f(g(x)) => compose(f)(g)
```

And we find this pattern in our new `add1_mul_add` -

```
f = compose(add)
g = add1_mul
f(g(x)) = compose(add)(add1_mul(x))
```

And we reduce it to pointfree and we got our new `add1_mul_add` function:

```
const add1_mul_add = compose(compose(add))(add1_mul)
```

But hey - we can reduce it even more!

```
const add1_mul_add = compose(compose)(compose)(add)(add1_mul)
```

And there we have found something that already exists in haskell under the name of [`The Owl`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Combinator_discoveries).

We can define it in Javascript simply as:

```
const owl = compose(compose)(compose)
```

But now, with every new function in the chain, you would have to create a higher order of the owl operator.

```
const owl2 = compose(compose)(owl)
const add1_mul_add_mul = owl2(mul)(add1_mul_add)

const owl3 = compose(compose)(owl2)
const add1_mul_add_mul_add = owl3(add)(add1_mul_add_mul)
```

So I really recommend having your functions unary in pointfree style. Or use other constructs like lists:

```
const actions = [ add, mul, add, mul ]
const values  = [ 1,   2,   3,   4   ]
const add_mul_add_mul = (...values) => zip(actions, values).reduce((acc, [action, value]) => action(acc, value), 0)
```

Comment: wow that just works.. but it works just with 2 functions to compose, if further functions are needed to compose same pattern should be nested, like: `add_1_and_multiply_and_add = R.uncurryN(2, R.compose(R.add, R.uncurryN(2, R.compose( R.multiply, R.add(1)))))` -> `add_1_and_multiply_and_add(3, 5, 6)  //> 26`, it seems possible to implement a `spread_compose` function that does the job for any number of functions

Comment: It works only with 2 functions because in theory `compose` is a binary function. So if you want to add another function to the "chain", you have to compose it with already composed function. I will update the answer acordingly.